# cordova inappbrowser plugin automatically keep authentication info

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I use Cordova Inappbrowser plugin to load third party content, but there is an issue that only the first time I install the app, the authentication window will appear, the second time i open the app ,it just skip the authentication part as if it keep the info already, even if i already exit app thread last time, it still keep the authentication info .I want to know how I can improve this ,i cannot uninstall and install every time just to input authentication message.

Comment: Do you mean authentication of 3rd party like FB?

Comment: yes, the authentication part is provided by 3rd party.